# Why does Telegram bot automatically convert GIF to WEBM format?

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot, gif

I am trying to send a GIF file to a user in a telegram bot. However, instead of a GIF file, telegram sends WEBM format. I think it is for optimization purposes. But, the file weighs 600KB.

```
private void sendDocument(FaceSwapperResponseDto image, String chatId) {
        BotInitialize bot = LegramContextHolder.getContext().getBot();
        String filePath = "file.gif";
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            fos.write(image.getImageBytes());
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        File file = new File("file.gif");

        SendAnimation animation = new SendAnimation();
        animation.setChatId(chatId);
        animation.setAnimation(new InputFile(file));
        bot.execute(animation);
    }
```

I tried sendDocument, sendAnimation but, I am still receiving a file in incorrect format.

[image]

Comment: _"the file weighs 600KB"_ -- what makes you say that?  Your screenshot says 18.9KB.

Comment: Actual GIF file is 600KB. After that, telegram compresses and converts to webm format. Thus, now it is 18.9KB.

Comment: OK, so what is the question? You want Telegram to send it uncompressed as the original .gif?  The question is unclear.